# Android Paint: can I save drawn image as XML available for the future editing?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-sdk-tools

Can I save the drawn image (by `android.graphics.Paint;`, `android.graphics.Canvas;`, `android.graphics.Path;` etc.) as XML which will be available for the editing?

Currently, I know that we can save the drawn image like this way:

```
String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(), 
       UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png","drawing");
```

Maybe we should the PNG copy for the gallery, however to make it editable we also need the vector XML-copy.

Comment: There is no way to convert bitmap image to vector I think. Atleast no simple way. What I'd suggest is to store all user actions in some format like *User drawn a line from 122:85 to 186:33*, and save it as a string somehow. And when need to restore - just repeat those actions.

Comment: Thank you for the comment answer. We don't need to convert bitmap to vector. Capturing the XML of drawn image before it saved as bitmap for the first time will be enough to solve this problem, however it is possible?

Comment: image is drawn as a bitmap, not as XML, there is no XML source of every image.

Comment: I see. Looks like it's required to track the user's finger and generate the XML `<vector>` ...